# Getting the sum of a calculated column

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

Currently I have a table that spits out the name of a Dog Walker, the Dog they're walking, and how much time they have spent walking the dog in each specific session.

Here's what it looks like:

```
SELECT WALKERS.LastName ||', '|| WALKERS.FirstName AS WalkerName, DOGS.Name 
AS DogName,
(trunc( extract(hour from endtime) * 60 + extract(minute from endtime))
 - (extract(hour from starttime) * 60 + extract(minute from starttime)) ) / 
60 AS LengthInHours

FROM WALKERS, DOGS, CUSTOMERS, JOBS

WHERE DOGS.OwnerPhoneNum = CUSTOMERS.phonenumber AND Walkers.PhoneNumber = 
JOBS.WalkerPhoneNum AND CUSTOMERS.phonenumber = JOBS.customerphonenum;
```

and some of the table elements look like:

```
| WALKERNAME    | DOGNAME | LENGTHINHOURS
| Francis, Kay  | Daisy   | .5
| Fowler, Rex   | Coco    | 1
| Carlson, Bell | Axel    | .5
| Carlson, Bell | Axel    | 1
```

The two appearances of Bell Carlson is where my issue is. I want to sum the length that each person has spent walking a specific dog, rather than their individual sessions, to look like:

```
| Carlson, Bell | Axel | 1.5
```

I believe I have to either create some type of join or subquery to sum these together, but I've been unable to implement anything that works.

Comment: Please don't use old-fashioned and not advised JOIN syntax in WHERE clause. Rewrite your joining logic to use JOINs instead.

Comment: you really use phone number as primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `SUM` to compute the total:

```
SELECT
    WALKERS.LastName ||', '|| WALKERS.FirstName AS WalkerName
,   DOGS.Name AS DogName
,   SUM((trunc( extract(hour from endtime) * 60 + extract(minute from endtime))
 - (extract(hour from starttime) * 60 + extract(minute from starttime))) / 
60) AS LengthInHours
FROM WALKERS w
JOIN JOBS j ON w.PhoneNumber = j.WalkerPhoneNum 
JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON c.phonenumber = j.customerphonenum
JOIN DOGS d ON d.OwnerPhoneNum = c.phonenumber
GROUP BY w.LastName ||', '|| w.FirstName, d.Name
```

Use ANSI joins for readability and compatibility (this has been very much a requirement for the last decade or so).

Comment: What do you mean by compatibility?

Comment: @miracle173 Once you get into outer joins, old-style conditions break compatibility across RDBMS vendors (e.g. Oracle uses `(+)` vs. SQL Server's `*=` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced the joining logic for a modern approach using `JOIN` with conditions. Added `GROUP BY` clause and `sum()` aggregate function to properly sum hours length for each walker and dog pair. Also included table aliases for shorter code.

```
SELECT 
  w.LastName ||', '|| w.FirstName AS WalkerName, 
  d.Name AS DogName,
  sum((trunc( extract(hour from endtime) * 60 + extract(minute from endtime))
 - (extract(hour from starttime) * 60 + extract(minute from starttime)) ) / 
60) AS LengthInHours
FROM WALKERS w
JOIN JOBS j ON j.WalkerPhoneNum = w.PhoneNumber
JOIN DOGS d ON d.OwnerPhoneNum = c.phonenumber
JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON c.phonenumber = j.customerphonenum
GROUP BY 
  w.LastName ||', '|| w.FirstName,
  d.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I point out that your method of determining the length of the time spent walking is a bit strange, and is actually broken if there are any cases of walkers walking dogs through midnight (it doesn't take days into account)? If `endtime` and `starttime` are Oracle `DATE`s, then you can simply use

```
(endtime - starttime) * 24
```

Oracle's date arithmetic is expressed in days; multiply by 24 to get the number of hours.

I would suggest converting into hours after doing the aggregation:

```
SELECT walkername, dogname, SUM(walktime) * 24 FROM (
    SELECT w.lastname || ', ' || w.firstname AS walkername
         , d.name AS dogname, endtime - starttime AS walktime
      FROM walkers w INNER JOIN jobs j
        ON w.phonenumber = j.walkerphonenum
     INNER JOIN customers c
        ON c.phonenumber = j.customerphonenum
     INNER JOIN dogs d
        ON d.ownerphonenum = c.phonenumber
) GROUP BY walkername, dogname;
```

If `starttime` and `endtime` are `TIMESTAMP`s then I would suggest casting them to `DATE` to make the arithmetic easy:

```
SELECT walkername, dogname, SUM(walktime) * 24 FROM (
    SELECT w.lastname || ', ' || w.firstname AS walkername
         , d.name AS dogname
         , CAST(endtime AS DATE) - CAST(starttime AS DATE) AS walktime
      FROM walkers w INNER JOIN jobs j
        ON w.phonenumber = j.walkerphonenum
     INNER JOIN customers c
        ON c.phonenumber = j.customerphonenum
     INNER JOIN dogs d
        ON d.ownerphonenum = c.phonenumber
) GROUP BY walkername, dogname;
```

Hope this helps.